# Set multiple validator - Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to set multiple validator after control initialization but it seems it not adding the validators.

Code:

```
 this.infoForm.controls['email'].setValidators(this.DynamicValidation(validations));

 DynamicValidation(list: Array<string>): Array<ValidatorFn> {
  const validators: Array<ValidatorFn> = [];
  list.forEach((validator: string) => {
      if (validator === 'required') {
          validators.push(Validators.required);
          return;
        }
         // other validators implementation
    }
 }
```

Anothing thing, is there a way to set custom validator name with a flag like this "validators.push({ isMatching:false }". ?

Comment: You would have to return the created array I guess: `return validators;` after the foreach block.

Comment: is there posible to use validators.push({'isMatching':false) if I want to set a custom validator ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 this.infoForm.controls['email'].setValidators(this.DynamicValidation(validations));

 DynamicValidation(list: Array<string>): Array<ValidatorFn> {
  const validators: Array<ValidatorFn> = [];
  list.forEach((validator: string) => {
      if (validator === 'required') {
          validators.push(Validators.required);
          return validators;
        }
         // other validators implementation
    }
 }
```

Comment: is it possible to use validators.push({'isMatching':false) if I want to set a custom validator ?